# How to add a custom indicator to Shiny, R quantmod question

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod, shinyapps, technical-indicator

I'm new with this trying to add a custom indicator to Shiny/R quantmod app.

The below code in R script works well.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('SBUX')
barChart(SBUX)
# create new TA function
myInd <- function(x) {
  return(WMA(Cl(x)))
}
addMyInd <- newTA(FUN = myInd)
addMyInd()
```

The equivalent in shiny

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)

myInd <- function(x) {
  return(WMA(Cl(x)))
}
addMyInd <- newTA(FUN = myInd)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
observe({
  query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
  dataInput <- reactive({ as.xts(getSymbols('SBUX', auto.assign = FALSE)) })
  output$chart <- renderPlot({ chartSeries(dataInput(), name = 'SBUX', TA = c(addMyInd()) ) })  
 })
})
```

fails with the Error: could not find function "myInd".

Whereas replacing "addMyInd" with any of the inbuilt function works well.

```
output$chart <- renderPlot({ chartSeries(dataInput(), name = 'SBUX', TA = c(addWMA()) )
```

Any idea how to make Shiny find the "myInd" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might face a similar issue.

the trick is to put the two functions for the custom indicator inside another file and include it in server.R.

helper.R

```
library(quantmod)

myInd <- function(x) {
    return(WMA(Cl(x)))
}

addMyInd <- newTA(FUN = myInd)
```

and server.R just reads

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)

source("helper.R");

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
observe({
  query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
  dataInput <- reactive({ as.xts(getSymbols('SBUX', auto.assign = FALSE)) })
  output$chart <- renderPlot({ 
    chartSeries(dataInput(), name = 'SBUX', TA = c(addMyInd()) ) 
    }) 
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really try if it works, but based on my Shiny apps, you could try a) making it reactive:

```r
myInd <- function(x) {
  reactive(return(WMA(Cl(x))))
}
```

and b) putting it inside the server call:

```r
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  myInd <- function(x) {
    reactive(return(WMA(Cl(x))))
  }
  addMyInd <- newTA(FUN = myInd)

  observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    dataInput <- reactive({ as.xts(getSymbols('SBUX', auto.assign = FALSE)) })
    output$chart <- renderPlot({ chartSeries(dataInput(), name = 'SBUX', TA = c(addMyInd()) ) })  
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not work.  
If you may try.  
ui.R  
`library(shiny)  
shinyUI(
      plotOutput("chart", height = "565px")
)`  
server.R  
`library(shiny)  
library(quantmod)  
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  myInd <- function(x) {reactive(return(WMA(Cl(x))))}
  addMyInd <- newTA(FUN = myInd)  

observe({ query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
  dataInput <- reactive({ as.xts(getSymbols('SBUX', auto.assign = FALSE)) })
  output$chart <- renderPlot({ chartSeries(dataInput(), name = 'SBUX', TA = c(addMyInd()) ) })  
 })
})`

localhost:8100